# Use HTML dropdown list values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I'm trying to do:

*The user selects either option "One" or option "Two".
If the user select "One" the result is `66 + 45` or if the user select "Two" the result is `35 + 45`.*

How can I implement this using HTML and JavaScript?

This is what I've done so far:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="number">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>

...

// Result
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function test(eventInfo) {

  var userSelection = document.getElementById("number").value;

  if () {
    result = 66 + 45;
  } else {
    result = 35 + 45;
  }

  var greetingString = userSelection;
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = greetingString;

}
```

Comment: Note that innerText isn't supported in some browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
<select id="number">
  <option value="66">One</option>
  <option value="35">Two</option>
</select>
```

then:

```
result = 45 + +document.getElementById("number").value;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this. Set the values in data-attribute and calculate the sum.

```
<select id="number">
    <option value="1" data-Values="66,45">One</option>
    <option value="2" data-Values="35,28">Two</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

#### JS

```
 var values = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-Values');
 var sum = eval(values.split(',').join('+')); //Use with caution eval.
 document.getElementById("result").innerHtml = sum;
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xfkPs/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `value`:

```
<select id="number">
  <option value="66+45">One</option>
  <option value="35+45">Two</option>
</select>

var greetingString = $("#number option:selected").val(); 
// or document.getElementById("number").value;
document.getElementById("result").innerText = greetingString;
```

Comment: Do you want him to use eval? as from question it's clear, that he wants to actually add those numbers. Also how do you know he wants to use jQuery?

Comment: @Carlos eval is not recommended and he already know how to add 2 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use Switch Statement:

Html:

```
<select id="number">
  <option value="66">One</option>
  <option value="35">Two</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var userSelection = document.getElementById("number").value;

    switch (userSelection)
    {
    case 66:
      result = 66 + 45;
      break;
    case 35:
      result = 35 + 45;
      break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
<select id="number" onchange="test(this.value);">
  <option value="66+45">One</option>
  <option value="35+45">Two</option>
</select>

...

// Result
<div id="result">here</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
function test(val) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHtml = val;
}
</script>
```